# Operator overload in c++ class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Trying to overload the < and > operators in a c++ class

```
 template <typename T>
 bool BinaryTree<T>::operator < (BinaryTree<T> &B) {
   return (this->count < B.setCount(0));
 } 

template <typename T>
float BinaryTree<T>::setCount(float c)
{
  count += c;
  return count;
}
```

Where setCount(0) returns the count of the B obj. But this always outputs true no matter the numbers compared.

Changes my code to

```
template <typename T>
bool BinaryTree<T>::operator < (const BinaryTree<T> &B) {
  return (this->count < B.count);
}


printf("%c %lf\n", tree[0]->getData(), tree[0]->setCount(0));
printf("%c %lf\n", tree[1]->getData(), tree[1]->setCount(0));

Output >

a 0.750000
b 0.250000

if(tree[0] < tree[1])
   printf("0 < 1\n");
else printf("1 > 0\n");

Output > 

0 < 1
```

Comment: (Should probably be taking a `const&`.) What does your debugger tell you about the two values you're comparing when you run that code?

Comment: @Mat I doubt setCount is const.

Comment: Are you sure it's `B.setCount()` you need to compare to? My gut feeling tells me you want to compare to `B.count`! Oh, and it doesn't matter if `count` is private.

Comment: Try and print the value of ` B.setCount(0)` and `this->count` and manually check if its a flaw or something true . May be the condition is always true and you have not implemented `setCount` function correctly

Comment: setCount() is correct, printf doesn't work in the operator method

Comment: @andrei Sorry, "printf doesn't work in the operator method" ?? Unless you mean you're doing nested printf's there?

Comment: @andrei I code in c++ and cout does works

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: if `setCount` is a setter method, sure (and that comparator would scare the hell out of me). If it retrieves the count of a set (which would make much more sense in a comparison operator), then it could very well be const.

Comment: @Mat haha true... terrible naming.

Comment: updated my question with code

Comment: @andrei I think look at the above comment whether setcount or getcount is something you need to look for probably.

Comment: You're not helping us help you at all...

Comment: All I'm saying is that I tried putting printfs in my operator method and they never show :/

Comment: @andrei: I don't understand what the "output" is in your edit. You're referring to things we know nothing about; what's these "indexes" you talk about? What's the type of those `count` members? What exact values do they have when you enter that operator?

Comment: @andrei Did you terminate the printfs with a `\n`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Thanks  for your suggestion . I am learning slowly how things work in stackoverflow and what should be an answer and what should be a comment :)

Comment: Create and post a minimal snippet that exhibits the problem.  It should include these three things: the `operator<` method, the constructor that initialises the member variables, and the `setCount` method.  (Although to me it seems like `setCount` is broken.)

Comment: Is `count` actually a floating point number?

Comment: @juanchopanza I guess so, otherwise setCount(0) wouldn't print fractions...

Comment: @andrei Can you set a breakpoint on the content of the `operator<` and see if the program actually executes it?

Comment: @MrLister indeed. But I think the problem is in the comparison, see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
  printf("%c %lf\n", tree[0]->getData(), tree[0]->setCount(0));
  printf("%c %lf\n", tree[1]->getData(), tree[1]->setCount(0));
```

suggests to me that `tree` holds **pointers** to your `BinaryTree<T>`.

Here, you are comparing pointers, i.e memory addresses, not values:

```
if(tree[0] < tree[1])
   printf("0 < 1\n");
else printf("1 > 0\n");
```

You probably need

```
if(*(tree[0]) < *(tree[1]))
   printf("0 < 1\n");
else printf("1 > 0\n");
```

Comment: Very good. I missed that; did have an idea that he might not be calling his defined `operator<`, but I was not sure why that might happen. This explains it.